# Split with multiple delimeters and special chartacter in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a REGEX for split string based on various strings and operator. How we can do this?

Below is my code:

```
var author;
var authorResult = [];
ByREGEX=/By|From|says\s|,/g;
author = authorByline.split(ByREGEX);
if(!author[1].trim()) {
   author[1] = author[2].trim();
   author[2] = '';
}
authorResult['name'] = author[1].trim();

if("2" in author){
   authorResult['role'] = author[2].trim();
} else {
   authorResult['role'] = '';
}

return authorResult;
```

Below is my string and expected out:

```
From Bru Water(Delimeter:From) : Expected output(Author: Bru Water, Role:'')

By Matth Moo, Med Corresponde(Delimeter:'By' , ',') : **Expected output(Author: Matth Moo, Role:Med Corresponde)**

Analysis by Davidd Cross in London(Delimeter:'Analysis by' , 'in') : **Expected output(Author: Davidd Cross, Role:'')**

left and right, says Daavid Aaronovi(Delimeter:'says'): **Expected output(Author: Daavid Aaronovi, Role:'')**

From Dav Chart and Bo De(Delimeter:'From','and') : **Expected output(Author1: Dav Chart, Role1:'',Author2: Bo De, Role2:'')**

By Oliv Wrig, Poli Edit, and Franc Ellio, Politic Edit(Delimeter:'By','and'): **Expected output(Author1: Oliv Wrig, Role1:'Poli Edit',Author2: Franc Ellio, Role2:'Politic Edit')**

By RCAik Brbent(Delimeter:'By'): Expected output(Author: RCAik Brbent, Role:'')

From TomTY Knowl, Technolog Reporte(Delimeter:'From',','): **Expected output(Author: TomTY Knowl, Role:'Technolog Reporte')**
```

Comment: can you add a string delimiter to the strings?

Comment: Hi nina, I have added delimiters to all strings

Comment: Think I would create a strategy pattern and implement a strategy for each case returning author and role. Then run all strategies per line to produce an array of results. Would be a more readable, testable and maintainable solution in my opinion. `if (_.includes(authorByline.toLowerCase(), 'from'))` could be the beginning of one of the strategies (using lodash)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something really big using splits and join

There's still some problem like `Davidd Cross in London`

Also it returns an array and not an object

tell me in comment if you need me to clean the datas more but I think you should be able to do it by youself from this

---

use arrays to set identifiers and separator between authors, role and other authors,
and run them all against the string

```js
let lines = [
  "From Bru Water", // : Expected output(Author: Bru Water, Role:'')
  "By Matth Moo, Med Corresponde", // : **Expected output(Author: Matth Moo, Role:Med Corresponde)**
  "Analysis by Davidd Cross in London", // : **Expected output(Author: Davidd Cross, Role:'')**
  "left and right, says Daavid Aaronovi", // : **Expected output(Author: Daavid Aaronovi, Role:'')**
  "From Dav Chart and Bo De", // : **Expected output(Author1: Dav Chart, Role1:'',Author2: Bo De, Role2:'')**
  "By Oliv Wrig, Poli Edit, and Franc Ellio, Politic Edit", //: **Expected output(Author1: Oliv Wrig, Role1:'Poli Edit',Author2: Franc Ellio, Role2:'Politic Edit')**
  "By RCAik Brbent", // : Expected output(Author: RCAik Brbent, Role:'')
  "From TomTY Knowl, Technolog Reporte" // : **Expected output(Author: TomTY Knowl, Role:'Technolog Reporte')**
]

let nameIdentifier = ["from", "says", "by"] // these are followed by an Author name
let authorsSeparator = ["and"] // these are between two Authors
let authorRoleSeparator = [","] // these are between an Author and it's role
let tempSeparator = "somethingWhichAppearNowhereElse"

let result = lines.map(line => {
  // get authors
  let authors = line
  authorsSeparator.forEach(separator => {
    authors = line.split(separator).join(tempSeparator)
  })
  authors = authors.split(tempSeparator)
  
  
  // remove first object of array if not an authors
  let keep = false
  nameIdentifier.forEach(identifier => {
    keep |= authors[0].toLowerCase().includes(identifier)
  })
  if(! keep) { authors.shift() } // remove the first entry from the array

  // remove the identifiers to get the authors name
  authors.forEach((auth, i) => {
    nameIdentifier.forEach(identifier => {
      let identifierIndex = auth.toLowerCase().indexOf(identifier)
      if(identifierIndex !== -1) {
        auth = auth.substring(identifierIndex + identifier.length)
      }
      authors[i] = auth.trim()
    })
  })

  // separator authors name from their roles
  return authors.map(auth => {
    let author = auth
    authorRoleSeparator.forEach(separator => {
      author = auth.split(separator).join(tempSeparator)
    })
    return author.split(tempSeparator)
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```js
function sentenceToAuthor(sentence) {
  //Check that sentence contains keyword
  if (sentence.match(/(\s|^)(by|from|says)\s/ig)) {
    //list of author names
    var returner = [];
    //flag if activation word triggered
    var found = false;
    //for each non-whitespace string-block
    sentence.match(/\S+/ig).forEach(function(word) {
      if (found === false) { // If activation word not reached
        if (['from', 'by', 'says'].indexOf(word.toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0) { // check if word is activation word 
          found = true;
        }
      } else if (found === true) { // If activated
        if (word === 'and') { // special case "and" pushes a seperator for later use
          returner.push(',');
        } else if (word[0] == word[0].toUpperCase()) { // If first letter is uppercase, add word to returner
          returner.push(word.replace(/\W/ig, ''));
          if (word.match(/\W$/ig)) { // If word ends in non-word symbol like ",", disable activation
            found = null;
          }
        } else { // If not uppercase word, disable activation
          found = null;
        }
      }
    });
    // join names and split by seperator
    return returner.join(" ").split(',').map(function(w) {
      return w.trim();
    });
  }
  return false;
}
//TESTS
var tests = [
  "From Bru Water",
  "By Matth Moo, Med Corresponde",
  "Analysis by Davidd Cross in London",
  "left and right, says Daavid Aaronovi",
  "From Dav Chart and Bo De",
  "By Oliv Wrig, Poli Edit, and Franc Ellio, Politic Edit",
  "By RCAik Brbent",
  "From TomTY Knowl, Technolog Reporte"
];
//Run tests
console.log(tests.map(sentenceToAuthor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Was playing around creating a solution using the strategy pattern proposed in the comments.

Didn't complete it but hope it shows the idea:

````
const lines = [
  "From Bru Water",
  "By Matth Moo, Med Corresponde",
  "Analysis by Davidd Cross in London",
  "left and right, says Daavid Aaronovi",
  "From Dav Chart and Bo De",
  "By Oliv Wrig, Poli Edit, and Franc Ellio, Politic Edit",
  "By RCAik Brbent",
  "From TomTY Knowl, Technolog Reporte"
];

// naive, always assume name and role being 2 words
const toUpperString = (wordArray) => {

    const noCommasUpperFirst = (str) => {
        return _.upperFirst(_.replace(str, ',', ''))
  } 

    return _.join(_.map(_.take(wordArray, 2), noCommasUpperFirst), ' ');
}

// assumes author to be the first two entries 
const createAuthorAndRole = (authorWordArray) => {

  const hasRole = _.includes(authorWordArray[1], ',');

  if (hasRole) {
    const roleWordArray = _.slice(authorWordArray, 2);

    return {
        author: toUpperString(authorWordArray),
      role: toUpperString(roleWordArray)
    }
  }

  return {
    author: toUpperString(authorWordArray)
  }
}

const simpleMatchStrategy  = (wordArray, word) => {
  const index = _.indexOf(wordArray, word);
  if (index !== -1) {
      return createAuthorAndRole(_.without(wordArray, word));
  }
}

const strategies = [
  (wordArray) => simpleMatchStrategy(wordArray, 'from'),
  (wordArray) => simpleMatchStrategy(wordArray, 'by'),
  (wordArray) => simpleMatchStrategy(wordArray, 'says')
]

const results = [];

lines.forEach((line) => {
    console.log("line:", line);

    const wordArray = line.toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g) || [];

  strategies.forEach((strategy) => {
    const result = strategy(wordArray);
    if (result) {
      results.push(result);
    }
  })
});

console.log(results)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdgxs8b5/
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that caputures name and role in groups:

`/(?:from|by|says|and)\s([A-z]+\s[A-z]+)(?:(?:,|\sand)\s([A-z]+\s[A-z]+))?/ig`

Author in group 1 and role in group 2.

You can try it out on https://regex101.com/

[image]

**Edit**: above regexp assumes 2 Word for name and role, improved to capture all uppercase words

`/(?:from|by|says|and)\s([A-Z\b\s]+)(?:(?:,|\sand)\s([A-Z\b\s]+))?/ig`

Comment: Thanks @cYrixmorten for your reply. I have another case string:- `From Tom Knowles, West Coast Technology Reporter` . In this case get only first 2 words in role. But i want  `West Coast Technology Reporter` this in role

Comment: You are right that it is assuming 2 word for name and role. Also tried removing case insensitivity and capture all upper case words after a delimiter but didn't get that working for all cases.

Comment: Made an edit to the answer that you can try, am on my mobile so not able to test it so easily.